Comparing Dates between 2 Sheets, Not Evaluating as true when conditions are met
function trackProgress() {
  var out = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  out.getRange("dataRange").sort({ column: 1, ascending: true });

  var progress = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Progress");
  progress.getRange("Plog").sort({ column: 1, ascending: true });
  var dRows = out.getLastRow();
  var pRows = progress.getLastRow();
  var pdate = progress.getRange("Pdate").getValues();
  var pCRpro = progress.getRange("CRpro").getValues();
  var pMpro = progress.getRange("Mpro").getValues();
  var outUser = out.getRange("UID").getValues();
  var outWeight = out.getRange("Rweight").getValues();
  var outDate = out.getRange("Date").getValues();
  var data;

  //[["Date", "CR", "CR Proj", "M", "M Proj"]]


  for (var i = 0; i <= dRows; i++) {
    for (var g = 0; g <= pRows; g++) {
Logger.log(outDate[i]+" "+pdate[g])

      if (outDate[i] == pdate[g]) {
        Logger.log("date match")
        if (outUser[i] == "Munchkin") {
          data = data.concat([[outDate[i], "", pCRpro[i], outWeight[i], pMpro[i]]]);
        }
        if (outUser[i] == "CR") {
          data = data.concat([[outDate[i], outWeight[i], pCRpro[i], pMpro[i]]]);
        }
      }
  
    }

    }
  

  Logger.log(data)


}

Ex Log
As shown in the Ex log there are several instances where pDate and outDate are equal, any help would be appreciated.
when the two dates match I want to concat the row of info a new array


 var pdate = progress.getRange("Pdate").getValues();
 var outDate = out.getRange("Date").getValues();
     if (outDate[i] == pdate[g]) {


There are two main issues. Firstly, pdate and outDate are 2D arrays and should not be compared the way shown in the code.
When you reference pdate[g], you get a subarray of values. In the event the named range Pdate has three columns, the subarray will look like [1, 2, 3]. If there is just one column, it will look like [1]. To compare a value within the subarray to another value, you need to reference a column within the array, as in pdate[g][0]. Assuming that both named ranges have one column, you can compare the values like this:
    if (outDate[i][0] == pdate[g][0]) { // note: this will never be true when the arrays contain objects such as Dates

Secondly, the logs you shared suggest that the two named ranges contain dates. In JavaScript, dates are handled as Date objects. Objects are different from primitives and cannot be compared the way shown in the code.
To find if two Date objects refer to the same moment in time, use Date.getTime(), like this:
    if (value1.getTime && value2.getTime && value1.getTime() === value2.getTime()) {

But in the Google Sheets context, if you are only comparing dates for equality, the easiest way to work with them would be to retrieve them as text strings in the format shown in the spreadsheet. Further, you can use Array.flat() to get 1D arrays, like this:
 const pdate = progress.getRange("Pdate").getDisplayValues().flat();
 const outDate = out.getRange("Date").getDisplayValues().flat();
   if (outDate[i] === pdate[g]) {

Note that this requires that the two named ranges use the same date format.

thank you sir.  I ended up changing how the data was stored allowing me to not use 2d arrays, but information on comparing dates was extremely helpful.

just out of curiosity. if im only comparing the first column of an 2d array do I still need to specify the column. in the log it seemed to retrieve the correct value.

"f im only comparing the first column of an 2d array do I still need to specify the column" — Range.getValues() always gets a 2D array. To access an individual value within a 2D array, you need to specify two indices. Expressions like Logger.log(outDate[i]+" "+pdate[g]) coerces those rows to String so what you see in the log is not accurate. Use console.log(JSON.stringify(outDate[i])); console.log(JSON.stringify(pdate[g]))); to get a representation that is easier to debug.

Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.
